# Turn off logging and debugging

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play

I spent 2 days looking for a solution to this problem, but to no avail,
when I try to publish my application on google play, I get this issue:

You have imported an APK or Android App Bundle that can be debugged. For security reasons, you must disable debugging before the applicable APK or Android App Bundle can be published on Google Play. Learn more about APKs or Android Bundle Bundle packages for which the Debug feature has been enabled.

Answer (score 1):

[Google: `"disable debugging" Google Playstore`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disable+debugging%22+Google+Playstore) → [Prepare for release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing) → [Turn off logging and debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing#turn-off-logging-and-debugging)

> **Turn off logging and debugging**
>
> Make sure you deactivate logging and **disable** the debugging option before you build your application for release. You can deactivate logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files. You can **disable** debugging by removing the `android:debuggable` attribute from the `<application>` tag in your manifest file, or by setting the `android:debuggable` attribute to `false` in your manifest file. Also, remove any log files or static test files that were created in your project.
>
> Also, you should remove all Debug tracing calls that you added to your code, such as `startMethodTracing()` and `stopMethodTracing()` method calls.
>
> > **Important**: Ensure that you **disable** debugging for your app if using [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display paid for content or if using JavaScript interfaces, since debugging allows users to inject scripts and extract content using Chrome DevTools. To **disable** debugging, use the [`WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)) method.

Answer (score 1):

Turn Off Development Build on the build settings box:

[image]